# ngdart generate component is not generating css file?

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

When I am trying to generate the component in Angular Dart. It is not generating style file (css file). Do I need to add any extra flag for that or this is issue with `ngdart cli` .

[image]

pubspec.yaml file

```
name: todo_list
description: Todo List
version: 0.0.1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.64.2 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  angular: ^5.0.0-beta+2
dev_dependencies:
  angular_test: ^2.0.0-beta+2
  build_runner: ^0.9.2
  build_test: ^0.10.3+1
  build_web_compilers: ^0.4.1
  pageloader: ^3.0.0-beta
  test: ^1.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving this command to see the list of options available

ngdart help generate component
ngdart help generate test

Ref : https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/angular_cli/latest/

And also try with option -p, it creates the component in a different folder instead of lib folder which is difficult to maintain when your components list keeps on growing .

example : ngdart generate component  -p

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same thing. I do not know if they changed anything in that so far. I created the following python script in case anyone needs to refer to it. It will create your component inside the /lib/src folder inside another folder with your component name and all the html css and dart file. This is more like ng generate component of Angular-cli.

https://github.com/rahulh25/generate_component_angulardart

Comment: Please don't use an external git repository to show your code, as it's not guaranteed to be static, it's not always accessible by all readers, and it's not immediately obvious where to look for the solution to the question. Instead, please [edit] your answer to include the code that's relevant to the question in the answer itself (using [formatted text](/editing-help#code), no images of code please!)

Comment: Actually there is no particular solution to this question. That is just how ngdart generate component is created. It is not similar to what ng generate component for angular-cli does. Therefore I created my own python script so that I can create the necessary files even if it is in a subfolder under /lib/src. It was for my personal use but seeing someone else might need it I put it on github and shares it here.  As for the github link it is public so anyone can use it. If there is any problem accessing it please do tell me and I will try and look into it.